# jVectorMap with multiple dataSeries

Tags: jvectormap

Using the jVectorMap World Map, I want to be able to display two different scales for different countries.

For example, have gradients from white to black for some countries and gradients from white to blue for the other countries.

How can I do that please?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take a look at [this demo](http://jvectormap.com/examples/world-gdp/) you can see that `series.regions` is an array. So you can just pass several series if you want to use more than one scale for the the visualization.